# Angular HTML Select option disable and enable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a html select option

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="field in filter.fields" value="{{field.id}}">{{field.name}}</option>
</select>
```

which I am iterating from ng-repeat , I want to disable option on basis of a filed selectable like

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="field in filter.fields" {field.selectable==true?enable:disable} value="{{field.id}}">{{field.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

How can I achieve this with angular?

Comment: Ordinarily to make a select list with angularjs you're using the ng-options directive though I don't know that it has built in support for disabling options (you may need to copy/tweak the source) the other directive to be aware of that might help with the way you're trying to handle this is ng-disabled http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled

Comment: Are you intentionally not binding the value of the `select` input to a model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-options with disabled rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows)

Comment: Not a duplicate in my opinion, since the way by which `<option>` elements are iterated and rendered is different.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming you have a structure like this:

```
  $scope.filter = {
    fields: [
      {id: 1, name: "a", selectable: false},
      {id: 2, name: "asdf", selectable: true},
      {id: 3, name: "qwet", selectable: false},
      {id: 4, name: "qnjew", selectable: true},
      {id: 5, name: "asdjf", selectable: false}
    ]
  };
```

This should work for you:

```
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="field in filter.fields" ng-disabled="field.selectable" value="{{field.id}}">{{field.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: I'd still recommend you have a look at m59's answer. The problems with my solution that he's highlighting might come back to bite you.

Answer (score 10):

While the ng-disabled attribute will technically work, you are likely to encounter bugs when using ng-repeat on options. This is a well known issue and is exactly the reason that the angular team created ng-options. There is not yet an angular implementation for using ng-options and ng-disabled together, but **Alec LaLonde** created this custom directive that you can add in and use. [See the issue forum here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/638](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/638) and the [jsfiddle from that post](http://jsfiddle.net/alalonde/dZDLg/9/).

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('optionsDisabled', [ '$parse', function($parse) {
        var disableOptions = function($scope, attr, $element, data, fnDisableIfTrue) {
            $element.find('option:not([value="?"])').each(function(i, e) { //1
                var locals = {};
                locals[attr] = data[i];
                $(this).attr('disabled', fnDisableIfTrue($scope, locals));
            });
        };

        return {
            priority: 0,
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function($scope, $element, attributes) { //2
                var expElements = attributes.optionsDisabled.match(/^\s*(.+)\s+for\s+(.+)\s+in\s+(.+)?\s*/),
                    attrToWatch = expElements[3],
                    fnDisableIfTrue = $parse(expElements[1]);
                $scope.$watch(attrToWatch, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (!newValue) return;

                    disableOptions($scope, expElements[2], $element, newValue, fnDisableIfTrue);
                }, true);

                $scope.$watch(attributes.ngModel, function(newValue, oldValue) { //3
                    var disabledOptions = $parse(attrToWatch)($scope);
                    if (!newValue) return;

                    disableOptions($scope, expElements[2], $element, disabledOptions, fnDisableIfTrue);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
//1 refresh the disabled options in the select element
//2 parse expression and build array of disabled options
//3 handle model updates properly

function OptionsController($scope) {
    $scope.ports = [{name: 'http', isinuse: true},
                    {name: 'test', isinuse: false}];

    $scope.selectedport = 'test';
}
```

Comment: I have updated the referenced JS Fiddle to work with JQLite: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7HXUH/)

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a fairly old question.  In the later version of Angular (angular 1.4+) you have the ngOptions directive.  Here is the link:-

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

There is now a syntax for handling this case:-

```
label disable when disable for value in array track by trackexpr
```

I thought I would put this in in case someone else visits this page.