# How to disable a <option> of select element when using AngularJS ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

Is there a way to disable an `option` in a `select` element when we populate `options` with ng-options in AngularJS?

Like this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp

You can do it by adding `ng-disabled` to each `<option>` tag, but is there a way to do it if we are using the `ng-options` directive in the `select` tag?

Comment: what do you mean by on tag and not on tag?

Comment: @IlanFrumer on select tag and not on option tag , i have edited my post :)

Comment: Yeah, just do it. It works.

Comment: @towr what i have is a select box that contains informations from mongoDB database i use the binding like this  : 
`<select class="form-control input-sm"
            ng-model="list"
            ng-options="value.label for value in lists">
 </select>`

And i want to disable the selected option but just after clicking on a button

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows

Comment: https://github.com/farazshuja/disabled-options

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to do this is, to forget using `ng-options` on the `select` element, and add the options in with `ng-repeat`, then you can add a `ng-disabled` check on each `option`.

http://jsfiddle.net/97LP2/

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <form ng-controller="ctrl">
        <select id="t1" ng-model="curval">
            <option ng-repeat="i in options" value="{{i}}" ng-disabled="disabled[i]">{{i}}</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="disabled[curval]=true">disable</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

a minimal controller for testing:

```
angular.module('myapp',[]).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.options=['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'];
    $scope.disabled={};
})
```

Comment: Yea I agree with @towr, I don't see a solution using ng-options in the select tag. I like this implementation it's clean and easy to understand.

Comment: It looks like Angular 1.4's [ngOptions](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) will allow `label disable when disable for ...`

Comment: @towr the solution works well for single dropdown, but what if we have multiple dropdowns populated from same single json? As in my case the option selected in one dropdown is disabled but not reflected in other dropdowns...

Comment: I think it should work if the lists use the same scope, so that might be the issue. 
One option is to put the options-list in the `$root` (probably not the nicest way to do it): http://jsfiddle.net/2dsoh7xq/

Answer (score 17):

From **Angular 1.4** : 
We can use `disable when` in ng-options, for example:

```
 $scope.colors = [
  {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
  {name:'white', shade:'light', notAnOption: true},
  {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
  {name:'blue', shade:'dark', notAnOption: true},
  {name:'yellow', shade:'light', notAnOption: false}
];
$scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red
```

This example have colors grouped by shade, with some disabled:

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name group by color.shade disable when color.notAnOption for color in colors"></select>
```

I got this code from [the angular documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: This is the best solution, but one thing worth pointing out is that it requires Angular 1.4 or above as @Fulup mentions. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ng-disabled` directive http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" ng-disabled="disableSelect">
          <option val="one">First</option>
          <option val="two">Second</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="disableSelect = !disableSelect">
        Disable select
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Here you could find the complete example http://jsbin.com/ihOYurO/1/

Comment: cool example i had the same in my application but what i want is to disable the options inside the select and not the select ? Capiché ?

Comment: @badaboum yea that wasn't very clear at all in your question, write better questions and you'll get better answers.

Comment: @NicolasMoise i'm not a native English speaker ! peace

Comment: @badaboum no problem. I think what you actually meant to say was a great question. I just want other people to be able to understand it and link to it in the future as well. It's kind of the point of this website.

Answer (score 2):

Solve with version 1.4 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions [double check you look for v1.4 documentation]

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this

```
<button ng-click='disableSelect=true'></button>

<select ng-disabled='disableSelect'></select>
```

Comment: You sure? @luacassus's jsbin example seems to work and he uses the same logic

Comment: @NicolasMoise yes it si working absolutly well but i need to disable the option and not the select  ? any idea ?

Comment: @NicolasMoise need to edit the <select ng-disabled='disableSelect'></select>

Comment: Well this is very easy if you use ng-options instead of manually typing out the option tags.In your controller, you'll have an array containing the options of your select (their value, label, etc...) then just write a function that removes elements from that array and call it when you press the button.

Comment: @NicolasMoise Ah, I made a typo in my jsfiddle myself which caused it to fail, lol, that's ironic.