# How can I disable the already selected value from the dropdown using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to disable the already selected value from the dropdown using `ng-options` AngularJS.

```
<select name="fruit" ng-model="selectedFruits" ng-options="fruit as fruit.name for fruit in fruits"></select>
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

$scope.selectedFruits = undefined;
$scope.finalSelectedFruits = [];

$scope.fruits = [{'name':'banana', 'color':'green'}, 
                 {'name':'apple', 'color':'red'}, 
                 {'name':'mango', 'color':'yellow'}];

$scope.add = function() {
   $scope.model.finalSelectedFruits.push($scope.selectedFruits);
};
```

Please look at the following image

[image]

You can see `mango` is already selected. How can disable it in the new dropdown based on the `$scope.selectedFruits`.

**I don't want to do this within** `<options></options>`

Comment: I'm not sure about disabling a single select-option item, but why not remove it from the array, thus removing it from the options?

Comment: What would a `disabled` option look like?  Do you want the value filtered out?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no straight approach to achieve this but in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows you can find a solutions that can work for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/72q64E0HoDWbQXviRPeg?p=preview

on ng-change check the value and make ng-disabled to true

I concur with @maurycy. Please follow the custom directive approach, given in [ng-options with disabled rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows)