# Disabled selected item in Angular for other Select Option Fields of the same Items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I've been struggling on this for a while... I'm currently using Angular.

Let's say we have five select option fields and that we are iterating through the same list for each one.

Our options are:

```
$scope.items = [one, two, three, four, five];
```

If I choose one, how would I disable the selected option for the remaining select option fields?
And if I go to another select option field and select an available item, it then disables that item for all the other fields.

Any help or even guidance on how to do this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So you still want see them in the select option fields, but not selectable when they have already been taken by any other select option fields?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? **[plunker remove item](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBqnTlxobUpiYxfhyJuj?p=preview)** or **[plunker disabled item](http://plnkr.co/edit/5weXSo9pmovjJDURcpY4?p=preview)**

Comment: I would mark that as the best answer, but it's a comment.

Comment: then I'll answer it then :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible solutions that you may want, and it depends on what kind of disabling your specs require.

1. Disable by removing the items that are already selected from other **`select`** elements. This solution requires a filter that removes the items that has already been selected except for the current item that the current **`select`** tag has selected.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBqnTlxobUpiYxfhyJuj?p=preview)**

***Javascript***

```
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $scope.data = [];

  })

  .filter('arrayDiff', function() {
    return function(array, diff) {
      var i, item, 
          newArray = [],
          exception = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

      for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        item = array[i];
        if(diff.indexOf(item) < 0 || exception.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
          newArray.push(item);
        }
      }

      return newArray;

    };
  });
```

***HTML***

```
<select 
  ng-repeat="(modelIndex, itemValue) in items track by modelIndex"
  ng-model="data[modelIndex]"
  ng-options="item for item in $parent.items | arrayDiff:data:data[modelIndex]">
  <option value="">Select Number</option>
</select>
```

---

2. Disable by setting a **`disabled`** property to the option items, this is actually a complex way of solving the problem as it does not use the standard angular **`select`** `ng-option` syntax. By using an `ng-repeat` to iterate over items and add an `ng-disabled` expression that evaluates the current selected item against other selected items from other **`select`** elements.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/5weXSo9pmovjJDURcpY4?p=preview)**

***Javascript***

```
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    this.items = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    this.data = [];

  })

  .filter('hasIntersection', function() {
    return function(item, array) {
      return array.indexOf(item) >= 0;
    };
  });
```

***HTML***

```
<select
  ng-repeat="(selectIndex, itemValue) in Demo.items"
  ng-model="Demo.data[selectIndex]">

  <option value="" ng-selected="Demo.data[selectedIndex] == item">
    Select Number  
  </option>

  <option ng-repeat="item in Demo.items"
          value="{{item}}"
          ng-disabled="item | hasIntersection:Demo.data"
          ng-selected="Demo.data[selectIndex] == item">
    {{item}}
  </option>

</select>
```

Comment: Your answer is great @ryeballar how can we do this for multi select using Angularjs.

Answer (score 3):

`ng-disabled` is your friend here, however I think you may face some problems with dynamic selects in IE.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ca6l2sHjN2PRykidm9kx?p=preview

Comment: You are placing view information, the disabled information, into the model. That information does not below in the model.

Comment: It would be better to have `ng-disabled="option == model[0]"`

Comment: Also to note that not using ng-options means that you will only get back the text between the <option> tag and not the object. Although there is currently no way to disable options when using ng-options. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows

Comment: Enzey,  'option == model[0]' - this works only for 2 drop downs, question was about 5. I think having a model for disabled is 100% ok since it changes dynamically. You can use <option> and have object as selected - just use <option value="{{whatever_u_want}}"

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-disabled.

```
<select ng-options="item in items" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-disabled="selectedItem"></select>
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/astrojason/4njwhdua/