# Disable selected options in other multi select option fields of the using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I am appending dynamic multi select boxes, what is my question is,  I want to disable all the selected options in other multi select boxes. I have tried [Disabled selected item in Angular for other Select Option Fields of the same Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537584/disabled-selected-item-in-angular-for-other-select-option-fields-of-the-same-ite/27596918#comment80235317_27596918) the answer from the above link, but it is for select box not for multi select. I have tried the answer for multi select, but there is some complication.

The above link is for dynamic select box. I want to do the same thing in multiselect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `disable when` in `ngOptions` to disable, and `filter` to remove items:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
  vm = this;
  
  vm.optionsA = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  vm.optionsB = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  vm.optionsC = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  vm.selectA = [];
  vm.selectB = [];
  vm.selectC = [];
  
  vm.disable = function(i) {
   return vm.selectA.indexOf(i) >= 0;
  }
  
  vm.filter = function(i) {
   return vm.selectA.indexOf(i) < 0;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
  <select multiple ng-model="ctrl.selectA" ng-options="t for t in ctrl.optionsA">
  </select>
  {{ctrl.selectA}}
  <select multiple ng-model="ctrl.selectB" ng-options="t disable when ctrl.disable(t) for t in ctrl.optionsB">
  </select>
  {{ctrl.selectB}}
  
    <select multiple ng-model="ctrl.selectC" ng-options="t for t in ctrl.optionsC | filter:ctrl.filter">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Now, it's even more unclear what you're asking. Give an example of what should happen.

Comment: Please see this link for disabling select option, same thing i need for multi select. http://plnkr.co/edit/BBqnTlxobUpiYxfhyJuj?p=preview

Comment: @KannanK So you don't want to disable, but you want to remove the selected values from the other boxes?

Comment: Disable or remove @hansmaad I want to stop selecting the same option again in the another select box.

Comment: Ok, then it's the other way around. I updated my code with axample for disable and removal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156643/discussion-between-kannan-k-and-hansmaad).