# How can I disable options for different selects in order to have always different options selected?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

I'm working with Angularjs.

HTML:

```
<select name="questionId1" ng-model="abCtrl.form.questionSel.q1" ng-options="question.val for question in abCtrl.form.questions track by question.index"></select>

<select name="questionId2" ng-model="abCtrl.form.questionSel.q2" ng-options="question.val for question in abCtrl.form.questions track by question.index"></select>
```

I'd like the option the user selects will be disabled for the other selection and vice versa

Comment: why are you don't use two different model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `ng-options` with `ng-repeat`-ed options can be assimilated to a regression...

You can use `... disable when ...` syntax in `ng-options`:

**First `ng-options`:**

```
...  disable when (question.index === questionSel.q2)  ...
```

**Second `ng-options`:**

```
...  disable when (question.index === questionSel.q1)  ...
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4xmdLc7/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use different approach, like this

```
<select name="questionId1" ng-model="abCtrl.form.questionSel.q1">
<option ng-repeat="question in abCtrl.form.questions" value="{{question.val}}" 
ng-disabled="abCtrl.secondSelectValue == question.val"
ng-selected="abCtrl.firstSelectValue == question.val">{{question.val}}
</option>
</select>
```

abCtrl.firstSelectValue would be default value of ur select box (otherwise it would have empty selection first time)

Comment: and just invert this for second select

Comment: do you think it's possible doing that using just <select> tag?

Comment: Because in that way the first option is like 
'<option value="? object:35 ?"></option>'

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

- Look at the stack post: [ng-options with disabled rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows). A good solution is explained
- Use a multi-slect component, by instance: http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

Comment: I have two different select with same options value and content, I want to disable in selB what I've selected in selA and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try on  angular `ngDisabled` there is lot of example's available in net could you please surf it . Also here I am attaching some sample code like

for `ngDisabled`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sample">
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
   angular.module('sample',[]).controller('sampleCntrl',function($rootScope){
   $rootScope.disableVal= true;
   });
</script>
<div ng-controller="sampleCntrl">
<p>
<button ng-disabled="disableVal">Click Me!</button>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitch"/>Button
</p>
<p>
<button ng-disabled="disableVal">Click Me!</button>
</p>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitch"/>Button
</p>
<p>
{{ mySwitch }}
</p>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've to disable the option selected in selA into selB... how can ng-disabled help me?

Comment: I updated the answer please check and my idea is set the `ngDisabled` var as `$rootScope` .Then where ever we click it will automatically  update's every where we used also concentrate on `ng-model`.