# Why I get an empty option (the first one) using ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

The first one appear like below:

```
<option value="? number:0 ?"></option>
```

HTML:

```
<select name="questionId1" class="questionId1 form-control required" tabindex="3" ng-model="abCtrl.form.questionSel.q1.index" ng-change="abCtrl.changeFn()" >
    <option ng-repeat="question in abCtrl.form.questions" value="{{question.index}}"
            ng-selected="question.index == abCtrl.form.questionSel.q1.index">{{question.val}}
    </option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
this.form={
           questions:      [],
           questionSel:    {q1:{index:0,}, q2:{index:1}},
}
```

form.questions is filld in by an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the value bound to the `ng-model` variable doesn't match any option value:

```
ng-model="abCtrl.form.questionSel.q1.index"
```

*Important:*

Comparison with `question.index` is ***strict***: types must also match.

When you use repeated options instead of `ng-options`, i.e. when you write `value="{{question.index}}"`, the value of the option becomes a **string**. Therefore the value of the variable in `ng-model`, which is a **number** does not match, and you get an empty option.

With `ng-options` you would avoid this problem as you can bind other types than strings for the options:

```
<select name="..." ng-model="abCtrl.form.questionSel.q1.index" ng-options="question.index as question.val for question in abCtrl.form.questions">
</select>
```

Comment: No, it's not for this reason, even If I change to ".form.questions.index" it doesn't work.

Comment: Types should also match. And according to the empty option generated, your `index` are numbers.

Comment: So what should I do? Sorry but I haven't caught it

Comment: I used ng-options, but because I have two selects, with same options and both the select can't have the same selected option, I was suggested to use ng-repeat in the option tag

Comment: Hm, looks like an advice in the wrong direction. At least I don't see why it would not be possible with `ng-options`. Do you have the link to the question, where you were told that?

Comment: Yes sure
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345399/how-can-i-disable-options-for-different-selects-in-order-to-have-always-differen

Comment: Should have used `... disable when (question.index === questionSel.q2) ` and vice-versa in `ng-options` : see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4xmdLc7/). Does it correspond to what you need?

Comment: Yes exactly, but you've got '<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>'
Anyway why it doesn't work with ngRepeat on options?
I mean, it works as well, but if I change value it keeps the first disabled option on the second select.

Comment: `<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>` is because I've left unset variables binded in `ng-model`. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4xmdLc7/1/). The `index` property is a number that's why it doesn't work (doesn't match) with `ngRepeat`