# ng-disable not working with ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-disabled

This is only happening when I am using directive

Template: (userlist.html)

```
<select id="teamUsers" ng-model="selectedUser.selected" data-placeholder="Select User" chosen="" class="chosen-select input-md"
        ng-options="user.ID as user.FirstName+' '+user.LastName+', '+user.Team.Name for user in teamUsers"
        ng-disabled="accessDisabled()">
    <option disabled></option>
</select>
```

Directive:

```
    App.directive('selectUser', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'userlist.html',
            controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $rootScope) {
                $scope.teamUsers = {
                              ID:1,
                              FirstName:'John',
                              LastName:'Doe',
                              Team:{
                                      Name : 'Web Team'
                                    }
                };
                $scope.accessDisabled = function () {
                    return !$rootScope.HasPermission('ChangeUserControl', 'Control'); // checking permission with return true and false.
                }
                $timeout(function () {
                    //$scope.teamUsers http request basically
                });
            }]

        };
    });
```

Using in View :

```
<select-user></select-user>
```

everything is working perfectly fine, I don't know why ng-disable is miss behaving in my senerio dropdown is not disabling

Comment: This issue is considered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows Check out.

Comment: This issue is considered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows Check out.

Comment: @alexey I want to disable the select control not the options , well thanks for your help bro :)

Comment: Are you sure that the $accessDisabled function is being called and is returning true?

Comment: Yes I am sure leave the function when I place the ng-disabled=true it still not working with this...