# Disable ng-options value dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-disabled

I want to disable select option which is in loop. So far i have implemented in following link. Its working way I wanted but i have made code very long. Is there any other way to implement.

[Code Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0p4q3b3s/34/)

```
<div ng-controller="OptionsController">
<button value="add" ng-click="add()">
add
</button>
<div ng-repeat="val in v">
    <select ng-model="val.myColor" ng-change="call(c.name)">
        <option ng-repeat="c in colors" ng-disabled="c.shade=='dark'" value="{{c.name}}">
            {{c.name}}
        </option>
    </select>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ng-options with disabled rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows) has some details on how to use ng-options with disabled options.

Based on your current use of the ng-repeat: http://jsfiddle.net/rhz8hxL5/1/

```
<div ng-controller="OptionsController">
  <button value="add" ng-click="add()">
    add
  </button>
  <div ng-repeat="val in v">
    <select ng-model="val.myColor" ng-change="call()">
      <option ng-repeat="c in colors" ng-disabled="isDisabled(c)" value="{{c}}">
        {{c}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS - I simplified it a bit for clarity in demonstration

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

function OptionsController($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.v = [{
    myColor: 0
  }];

  $scope.inUse = [];
  $scope.isDisabled = function(name) {
    return $scope.inUse.indexOf(name) !== -1;
  }

  $scope.colors = ['black', 'white', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'];

  $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.v.push({});
  }

  $scope.call = function() {
    $scope.inUse = [];

    for(var i=0; i<$scope.v.length; i++) {
      var val = $scope.v[i];

      $scope.inUse.push(val.myColor);
    }
  }
}
```

In English:

The `$scope.inUse` array is maintaining a list of currently selected values. When you change a dropdown value it invokes the `call` function. That function empties the `$scope.inUse` array and re-populates it with the currently selected values.

The `$scope.isDisabled` function returns a boolean on the basis that "*If it has an index it is in use and thus disabled*"

Comment: Thank you. But i dint understand using index in disable function. Please can you help me set default value for select box. Suppose If I am selected Friday and when i click on add next select box should show Monday. I have also added delete button. Even though delete is working I am not able to enable deleted entry for next add. Please help me with this flow. Angular is new to me.

Comment: Added an explanation of the functions to the answer. If you post a link to your current code I can take a look

Comment: Thank you. I understood concept. Here is my updated link http://jsfiddle.net/rhz8hxL5/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5u47mmto/1/ has a working version. Sets the value to the next available (non-selected) color, assuming a recycle to the start of the list if you meet the end. I've also updated the Add button to disable if all options are used.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of disabling is very straightforward and common practice. You could use the [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive instead of the `option` element, and save a line or two. The amount of the code in the controller has little to do with disabling the option.

Markup:

```
<select ng-options="c as c.name disable when disableColor(c) for c in colors track by $index" 
    ng-model="val.myColor" ng-change="c.call(c.name)">
</select>
```

New Controller function:

```
$scope.disableColor=function(c){
    return c.shade=='dark';
}
```

Comment: Is that ng-disabled not applied to the select?

Comment: You know, you're right,. I copy/pasted the wrong syntax. There's a disable when syntax. (See more [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/11017) Editing original answer.