# AngularJS: ng-option disable for legacy version

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-options

To start, I am a noob junior so please don't crucify me. ]

I'm trying to disable specific options in a select which is generated by angularJs.

so any select with a value 'tuesday' should be non-selectable and disabled.

I am currently using AngularJS v1.2

> **I cannot upgrade my version**

I am using the ng-options feature on a select to show a list of class names

```
 ng-options="class.id as class.name for class in classes"
```

The issue is when I add disable into that ng-options. It turns out that it is not supported in this version of AngularJS.

How would you go about making this happen?

Comment: Here's a directive which works with legancy version https://stackoverflow.com/a/20790905