# How to disable an Option in a select box using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two select boxes like below

```html
<select ng-model="secondCountry" id="secondCountry"  required class="form-control" >
         <option ng-value="0">Select 2nd Country</option>
  <option >india</option>
         <option >usa</option>
         <option >Japan</option>
 </select>
              

<select ng-model="thridCountry" id="thridCountry"   required class="form-control" >
 <option ng-value="0">Select 3rd Country</option>
 <option >india</option>
        <option >usa</option>
      <option >Japan</option>
</select>
```

My Goal is to disable or hide the option is selected on other that is , If i select the option `India` from `first select box` then I `dont need to select` the `Option India` from the `second select box`.

> NOTE : Iam loading the options by using ng-repeat

I tried the `ng-disabled="secondCountry"` Property but this disables the entire select box.

How to manage this ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-options-with-disabled-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manage this scenario with two way.
You have to bind your second `dropdown` with `ngChange` event like Below:

**First**

```
<select ng-model="secondCountry" id="secondCountry"  required class="form-control" >
  <option ng-value="0">Select 2nd Country</option>
  <option>india</option>
  <option>usa</option>
  <option>Japan</option>
 </select>


<select ng-model="thridCountry" id="thridCountry" ng-change="change()"  required class="form-control" >
 <option ng-value="0">Select 3rd Country</option>
 <option>india</option>
 <option>usa</option>
 <option>Japan</option>
</select>

$scope.change = function() {
  if($scope.secondCountry == $scope.thridCountry){
     $scope.thridCountry = '0';
  }
};
```

**Second**

you have disable those option which is selected on first `dropdown` with `ngDisabled`.

```
<select ng-model="thridCountry" id="thridCountry" ng-change="change()"  required class="form-control" >
    <option ng-value="0">Select 3rd Country</option>
    <option ng-disabled="secondCountry=='india'">india</option>
        <option ng-disabled="secondCountry=='usa'">usa</option>
      <option ng-disabled="secondCountry=='Japan'">Japan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your welcome @JIJOMONK.A.. Thanks for accept  my answer plz vote up :)