# Angularjs How can i disable particular option

Tags: angularjs

Please help me How can i disable paryicular option in my js code
This is My code

```
 <select  ng-options="bus.id as bus.BU for bus in bustatuses"
     options-disabled="bus.value==4 for bus in bustatuses">
                                    </select>
```

Here i wana to hide value=4 option

Thank you

Comment: possibly dupllicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202254/ng-options-with-disabled-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the below code, also please check this [plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/c1zDZLiolL9vqrAk) link for your scenario working example.

**Template:**

```
<select ng-model="busId">
      <option value="">Select Bus</option>
      <option ng-repeat="bus in bustatuses" ng-disabled="bus.id===4" value="bus.id">{{bus.BU}}</option>
</select>
```